# vagrant box cannot be detected after "suspend"

Tags: vagrant

After "vagrant suspend" on a Win7 (cygwin + Vagrant 1.6.3 + virtualbox + CentOS 6.5 as Guest), the box cannot be restarted:

```
$ vagrant status
Current machine states:
default                   not created (virtualbox)
```

How ever, I find the box withhin virtualbox, and if executed via the VB GUI, it runs and works.

Is that a known behaviour, and is there any solution?

Comment: What do you get when you do a `vagrant up` from that location? If you get an error that machine `default` already exists, it usually means you have another Vagrantfile somewhere with the same node name. If it's some other error, could you include it here with the question?

Comment: vagrant up recreates the box "Bringing machine 'default' up with 'virtualbox' provider... ==> default: Importing base box 'CentOS_6_5'..."

Comment: did you move your vagrant folder? I did this once without destroying the vagrant boxes and could see them with the virtualbox gui, but not with vagrant. vagrant status checks against the Vagrantfile in your current path (& upwards until it finds one). If you move your Vagrantfile to another folder wiuthout bringing along the .vagrant directory, it won't show a running machine. Actually, I'm not even sure if you *can* move a running machine at all by moving the .vagrant directory. You might just get the same zombie effect you described.

Comment: Hello @Dannid, no, unfortunately not. Just "vagrant suspend"

Answer (score 1):

I had this problem, where it seems to be more about Virtualbox than Vagrant. The answer was kindly given to me from a GitHub link - https://github.com/mitchellh/vagrant/issues/2969 All you had to do is get the Machine uuid from C:\Users[username]\VirtualBox VMs[Vagrant name][Vagrant name].vbox-prev and create the missing id file and paste in the Machine uuid under .vagrant\machines\default\virtualbox\id

Hopefully this works for you too.